# Render php image with own font

Tags: php, image, fonts, rendering, truetype

I want to use a own font (True Type) in this code:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: image/png");
// Email adres renderen
$email    =    "mail@mail.nl";
$length    =    (strlen($email)*8);
$im = @ImageCreate ($length, 20)
     or die ("Kan geen nieuwe afbeelding genereren");
$background_color = ImageColorAllocate ($im, 53, 88, 121); // Container BG: 53,88,121
$text_color = ImageColorAllocate ($im, 194, 212, 229);
imagestring($im, 3,5,2,$email, $text_color);
imagepng ($im);
?>
```

How can i change the font in: Open Sans Semibold? The path is ../fonts/opensans_semibold_macroman/OpenSans-Semibold-webfont.ttf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use imagestring function use imagettftext, this function allow use TTF fonts.

```
$font_file = "../fonts/opensans_semibold_macroman/OpenSans-Semibold-webfont.ttf";
﻿imagettftext ($im, 3, 0, 5, 2, $text_color, $font_file, $email);
```

Comment: Arguments not explained in answer but available on [php net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php)