# How add font php

Tags: php, fonts

I have such a small request because I have a php code and I do not know how to add a font to it, I know I have to add an imageloadfont but when it adds the generator just does not work. I've tried everything in my mind and nothing at all.

```
<?php

    if( isSet( $_GET[ 'Address' ] ) )
    {
        $szAddress = $_GET[ 'Address' ];
        $szExploded = explode( ":", $szAddress );
        $szServerIP = $szExploded[ 0 ];
        $szServerPort = $szExploded[ 1 ];
        $Query = new SourceQuery( );
        $Info    = Array( );
        $Rules   = Array( );
        $Players = Array( );
        try
        {
            $Query -> Connect( $szServerIP, $szServerPort, DEF__TIME_OUT);
            $Info    = $Query -> GetInfo( );
            $Players = $Query -> GetPlayers( );
            $Rules   = $Query -> GetRules( );
        }
        catch( Exception $e )
        {
            $Exception = $e;
        }
        $Query -> Disconnect( );
        header( "Content-type: image/png" );
        $rImage = imagecreatefrompng( DEF__IMAGE_NAME );
        $iColor = imagecolorallocate( $rImage, DEF__COLOR_RED, DEF__COLOR_GREEN, DEF__COLOR_BLUE );

        // bool imagestring ( resource $image , int $font , int $x , int $y , string $string , int $color )
        imagestring( $rImage, DEF__ADDRESS_TEXT_SIZE, DEF__ADDRESS_X, DEF__ADDRESS_Y, $szAddress, $iColor );
        if( $Info[ 'MaxPlayers' ] != 0 )
        {
            $szHostName = MIRAGE;
            $szMapName = $Info[ 'Map' ];
            if( strlen( $szHostName ) > DEF__HOSTNAME_MAX_TEXT_LEN )
            {
                $szHostName = substr( $Info[ 'HostName' ], 0, DEF__HOSTNAME_MAX_TEXT_LEN ). ' ...';
            }
            if( strlen( $szMapName ) > DEF__MAP_MAX_TEXT_LEN )
            {
                $szMapName = substr( $szMapName, 0, DEF__MAP_MAX_TEXT_LEN ). '..';
            }
            imagestring( $rImage, DEF__HOSTNAME_TEXT_SIZE, DEF__HOSTNAME_X, DEF__HOSTNAME_Y, $szHostName, $iColor );
            imagestring( $rImage, DEF__MAP_TEXT_SIZE, DEF__MAP_X, DEF__MAP_Y, $szMapName, $iColor );
            imagestring( $rImage, DEF__PLAYERS_TEXT_SIZE, DEF__PLAYERS_X, DEF__PLAYERS_Y, $Info[ 'Players' ]. '/' .$Info[ 'MaxPlayers' ], $iColor );
        }
        else
        {
            imagestring( $rImage, DEF__PLAYERS_TEXT_SIZE, DEF__PLAYERS_X, DEF__PLAYERS_Y, "SERVER OFF", $iColor );
        }
        $font_width = ImageFontWidth(5);  
        imagepng( $rImage );
        imagedestroy( $rImage );
    }
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Render php image with own font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26454455/render-php-image-with-own-font)